# Number satisfying certain conditions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b,c,d \in N$, such that $a>b,c>d$, $a\neq c$ and $\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b} =  \sqrt{c} -\sqrt{d}$. Is it true that all $a,b,c,d$ must be squares?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt{18}-\sqrt{8}=\sqrt{8}-\sqrt{2}.$
Lots of examples like this can be made by choosing $p,q,r,s$ with $p-q=r-s$ and then using $p\sqrt{m}-q\sqrt{m}=r\sqrt{m}-s\sqrt{m}$, and then moving $p,q,r,s$ "inside the radicals" which means squaring them.